# How to change apache2 127.0.0.1 name from localhost to another domain?

Tags: apache, apache-config, apache2.4

Sorry if this question is stupid, but I am a newbie when it comes to apache and servers in general and I have been trying but I can only find windows only answers. I'm running an apache server on a mint vm. When I type localhost, it redirects to the page automatically, same as doing 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1. Now, I want to change this to another domain name, but not a website one. Like, I want to change from the word localhost to another word, like 'local'. I have been unable to find answers, I have read about virtual hosts but I don't think that is it because I'm only running one website instance. This is just an example website btw, it's just a index.html file for me to learn how to configure things. I have changed my 000-default.conf to say ServerName thenameIwant but it doesn't work. I noticed it says that this is the last resort host what is the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use local to connect to your server, you would use local as a domainname which resolves to localhost or 127.0.0.1. You could do this by editing your hosts file. Depending on your os this file is stored in different places. Just google 'Change hosts file [your os]'. And add the following line: `local 127.0.0.1`.

The default apache server is set to listen for any domain, also local.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm on mint, as I said previously, a ubuntu based OS. It is /etc/hosts :) I thought I would have to change something in apache, but this is actually OS-related. Thanks a lot for your answer, all the googling I had done was wrong because I was unaware of these files and I was googling like apache change local domain and stuff. I found the host file in /etc/ and it is called hosts. Thanks a lot.